# How do I cleanly animate something sideways in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the divs to animate slowly sideways is this possible with JavaScript I'm pretty new to this and any help would be appreciated.

The code is here:

```js
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide();
    $(hash).show();
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide();
    $(hash).show();
});
```

```css
div {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}

#blue {
    background: blue;
}

#red {
    background: red;
}

#green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#blue">Show Blue</a> | <a href="#red">Show Red</a> | <a href="#green">Show Green</a>

<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/aUsHh/3/

Comment: the fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/aUsHh/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use an absolute-positioned set of coloured divs within a relative-positioned container.  See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aUsHh/13/

CSS:

```
#slidercontainer {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#slidercontainer div {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}
#blue {
    background: blue;
}

#red {
    background: red;
}

#green {
    background: green;
}
}
```

JS:

```
var hash = "";
if(window.location.hash) {
    if (hash != "")
    $(hash).hide("slow");
    hash = window.location.hash;
    $(hash).show("slow");
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $(hash).animate({'opacity': 0, 'left': "200px"});
    hash = window.location.hash;
    $(hash).css("left","-100px");
    $(hash).animate({'opacity': 1, 'left': "0px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code...

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide("slow");
    $(hash).show("slow");
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide("slow");
    $(hash).show("slow");
});
```

or for some sliding effect

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').slideUp("slow");
    $(hash).slideDown("slow");
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').slideUp("slow");
    $(hash).slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: thanks its slower now but din't achieve the slide effect can you help me with that too

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').slideUp();
    $(hash).slideDown();
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').slideUp();
    $(hash).slideDown();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUsHh/10/)

Answer (score 0):

try js like this

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide(1000);
    $(hash).show(1000);
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide(1000);
    $(hash).show(1000);
});
```

you can use time in jquery hide and show functions. it is 1000=1 sec.
or 
user a key word "slow" as default like this

```
 $('div').hide('slow');
 $(hash).show('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use [**fadeIn()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide();
    //change value accordingly for time
    $(hash).fadeIn(3000);
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('div').hide();
    //change value accordingly for time
    $(hash).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/aUsHh/14/)